# How to make a simple rounded button in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, storyboard

I just started learning iOS development, cannot find how to make simple rounded button. I find resources for old versions. Do I need to set a custom background for a button? In Android, I would just use a 9 patch, but I know iOS does not have this capability.

[image]

Answer (score 93, accepted):

To do it in the storyboard, you need to use an image for the button.

Alternatively you can do it in code:

```
 btn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
 btn.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: why is clipsToBounds needed? It seems, that shadow doesn't work until I remove it.

Comment: Good answer, but you can do it in IB, without images. See below.

Answer (score 275):

> Short Answer: **YES**

You can absolutely make a simple rounded button without the need of an additional background image or writing any code for the same. Just follow the screenshot given below, to set the runtime attributes for the button, to get the desired result.

It won't show in the `Storyboard` but it will work fine when you run the project.

[image]

**Note:** 
The **'Key Path'** `layer.cornerRadius` and value is 5. The value needs to be changed according to the height and width of the button. The formula for it is the height of button * 0.50. So play around the value to see the expected rounded button in the simulator or on the physical device. This procedure will look tedious when you have more than one button to be rounded in the storyboard.

Comment: Please add a comment when voting in negative.

Comment: it is disappointing that IB cannot show this like a run of the mill drawing app.

Comment: @WilliamCerniuk: Actually it can. Check out http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/

Comment: Setting the User Defined Runtime attributes does indeed work, viewable in the simulator after building.

Comment: As the accepted answer says, you may also need to add a Boolean key path `clipsToBounds` for this to work.

Comment: No need to import #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Answer (score 96):

You can do something like this:

```
@IBDesignable class MyButton: UIButton
{
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        updateCornerRadius()
    }

    @IBInspectable var rounded: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            updateCornerRadius()
        }
    }

    func updateCornerRadius() {
        layer.cornerRadius = rounded ? frame.size.height / 2 : 0
    }
}
```

Set class to `MyButton` in `Identity Inspector` and in IB you will have `rounded` property:

[image]

Comment: By far the best answer. Learned something new today awesome!

Comment: This answer is not complete. When you launch your app, xCode will use the frame size of the view in interface builder, not the real frame size when the app is running.

Comment: You can also use "didSet" instead of "willSet" and remove the argument isRounded.

Comment: If you use a background image, set `layer.masksToBounds = true` also

Answer (score 39):

1. Create a Cocoa Touch class.

[image]

2. Insert the code in RoundButton class.

   ```
   import UIKit

   @IBDesignable
   class RoundButton: UIButton {

       @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0{
           didSet{
           self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
           }
       }

       @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0{
           didSet{
               self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
           }
       }

       @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear{
           didSet{
               self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Refer the image.

[image]

Comment: Don't know if others ran into this, too, but as soon as I set the class to a button and give it a radius, border width and border color Xcode (9.2) throws an error that there was a rendering error. The app building succeeds but the red "!" keeps being displayed. Just saying... I switched back to the code only solution (although this was really an elegant way).

Answer (score 14):

I found the easiest way to do this, is by setting the cornerRadius to half of the height of the view.

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = button.bounds.size.height/2
```

Comment: No, I did not. If your height and width are the same (so it would have been square), then you would get a circle. But if the width is greater than the height, the button will be correct.

Comment: You're right, I missed the image included in the question that shows what the poster was actually after matches your answer more than the accepted answer - upvote

Answer (score 9):

Xcode 13 has added an option to do this by adjusting Corner Style Property (under BackgroundConfiguration).

Have to configure the background within Background Config, and then set View Background as default (nothing).

[image]

Comment: It should be noted that you need to change your button style from Default to Plain for these options to appear.

Answer (score 5):

Follow the screenshot below. It works when you run the simulator (won't see it on preview)

[image: Adding UIView rounded border]

Answer (score 4):

You can connect `IBOutlet` of yur button from storyboard.

Then you can set `corner radius` of your button to make it's corner round.

for example, your `outlet` is `myButton` then,

Obj - C

```
 self.myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0 ;
```

Swift

```
  myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
```

If you want exact round button then your button's `width` and `height` must be `equal` and `cornerRadius` must be equal to height or width / 2 (half of the width or height).

Answer (score 4):

As other answer have suggested to perform most of this work in code only one answer actually provided a way to view your changes in the storyboard IB Interface. My answer goes beyond that answer by allowing you to change the cornerRadius of the view, button, image, etc.

Please take a look at the following code. To use this code create a new swift file called RoundedView or whatever you would like to call it then go to your storyboard and change the class to either "RoundedView", "RoundedImageView" or "RoundedButton".

```swift
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class RoundedImage: UIImageView
{
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        updateCornerRadius()
    }

    @IBInspectable var rounded: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            updateCornerRadius()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.1 {
        didSet {
            updateCornerRadius()
        }
    }

    func updateCornerRadius() {
        layer.cornerRadius = rounded ? cornerRadius : 0
        layer.masksToBounds = rounded ? true : false
    }
}

@IBDesignable class RoundedView: UIView
{
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        updateCornerRadius()
    }

    @IBInspectable var rounded: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            updateCornerRadius()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.1 {
        didSet {
            updateCornerRadius()
        }
    }

    func updateCornerRadius() {
        layer.cornerRadius = rounded ? cornerRadius : 0
        layer.masksToBounds = rounded ? true : false
    }
}

@IBDesignable class RoundedButton: UIButton
{
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        updateCornerRadius()
    }

    @IBInspectable var rounded: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            updateCornerRadius()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.1 {
        didSet {
            updateCornerRadius()
        }
    }

    func updateCornerRadius() {
        layer.cornerRadius = rounded ? cornerRadius : 0
        layer.masksToBounds = rounded ? true : false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

change background default to custom
[image]

then give border radius

[image]

result is like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am using **Xcode Version 11.4**

In the attribute inspector, you can define the corner radius.

It won't show in the Storyboard but it will work fine when you run the project.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While adding `layer.cornerRadius` in the storyboard make sure that you don't have leading or trailing spaces. If you do copy paste, you might get spaces inserted. Would be nice if XCode say some kind of warning or error.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can do in code on  **UIKit and iOS 15+**

```
    var config = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
    config.cornerStyle = .capsule
    let btn = UIButton(configuration: config)
    btn.tintColor = .blue
```

Answer (score 0):

The extension is the best option for this problem. Create an extension of View or Button

```
public extension UIView {
  //Round the corners
  func roundCorners(){
    let radius = bounds.maxX / 16
    layer.cornerRadius = radius
  }
}
```

Call it from the code

```
button.roundCorners()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this!!

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as UIButton
   button.frame = CGRectMake(160, 100, 200,40)

   button.layer.cornerRadius =5.0
   button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
   button.layer.borderWidth = 2.0

   button.setImage(UIImage(named:"Placeholder.png"), forState: .Normal)
   button.addTarget(self, action: "OnClickroundButton", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
   button.clipsToBounds = true

   view.addSubview(button)
}
    func OnClickroundButton() {
   NSLog(@"roundButton Method Called");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class MyButton: UIButton
{
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()


    }

    func updateCornerRadius(radius:CGFloat) {
        layer.cornerRadius = radius
    }
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius:CGFloat = 0{
        didSet{
            updateCornerRadius(radius: cornerRadius)
        }
    }
}
```